# Loading a List Box from MySQL without duplicates with ASP and VS Basic

Tags: mysql, asp.net, drop-down-menu, asp-classic

I have a MySQL database, one table we'll call "General" and we'll give it two fields - "days" and "language". In the first part of a HTML form I'm asking for "days" which could be from 1 to 5000. In the second part I want to use the "days" information to go through the table, check only the rows where the number of days is less than "days", then determine the "language" and fill a drop down menu with the various languages without duplicating any of them. In theory this should be fairly easy, but I am so confused I'm not even sure where to start. Thanks greatly. Rick

Comment: Show some code please

Comment: "In theory this should be fairly easy, but I am so confused", you're not the only one!  Perhaps you could simplify or give more detail to your question.